# My Sql queries inorder to update it

Tags: mysql

How can I update over this query

```
$sqlquery = UPDATE("conference", 
                    array('area_of_expertise' => $area_of_expertise_id1, 
                          'long_name' => $_POST['longname'], 
                          'short_name' => $_POST['shortname'], 
                          'description' => $_POST['textarea'], 
                          'creator_id' => $get_id
                          ) 
                   );
```

I inserted all the need data in the conference table while making sure that it was the same data the user had chosen.

Comment: you should learn update query your syntex is wrong

Comment: I assume you're also using PHP. Is 'UPDATE' a self-defined function? I've never come across it before.

Comment: are you using a framework? what do you mean by "update over this query"? what have you tried?

Comment: Please provide more code. It looks like you are using some sort of library or a set of helper functions?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

Answer (score 0):

Your UPDATE query syntax is wrong.
You're not saying what table you want to update and which column of that table.

You're just saying UPDATE.

Syntax should be like :

UPDATE tableName SET column = value [ *WHERE someColumn = someValue* ]

Reference :
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're also using PHP. Is 'UPDATE' a self-defined function? I've never come across it before.

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE conference SET area_of_expertise = '" . $area_of_expertise_id1 . "', long_name = '" . $_POST["longname"] . "', short_name = '" . $_POST["shortname"] . "', description = '" . $_POST["textarea"] . "' WHERE creator_id = " . $get_id);
```

I'm only assuming your table and column names by the way.

Answer (score 0):

$query = "UPDATE conference SET area_of_expertise='$area_of_expertise_id1', long_name='$_POST['longname']', short_name='$_POST['shortname']', description='$_POST['textarea']' WHERE creator_id='$get_id'");

$update_value = mysql_query($query);

Hope that Helps.